# update table using another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

i have to update total_orders of customers column to be equal to the total number of all the orders placed by the customer(in cust_order)[image]

here is what i have tried

```
update (select * 
        from atish_customer a 
        inner join 
        (
            select cust_nbr,count(cust_nbr) as count_orders
            from atish_cust_order 
            group by cust_nbr
        )c
        on c.cust_nbr=a.cust_nbr) 
set tot_orders=count_orders;
```

But this is the error i get

```
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

Comment: Is that the diagram from _Mastering Oracle SQL_?

Comment: just curious as I am reading that right now

Comment: donno bro, my friend gave me a word document which had all questions needed to practice sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
UPDATE customer SET total_orders = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cust_order 
    WHERE cust_order.cust_nbr = customer.cust_nbr
)
```

[I'm not sure where your `atish_customer` and `atish_customer_order` comes into play...they're not shown in your diagram]

Explanation:  Basically the inner select just counts the number of orders from the cust_order table for each cust_nbr.  By joining the outer `customer.cust_nbr` to the inner `cust_order.cust_nbr`, each [outer] row will be updated with the correct total.  This is called a correlated subquery (see [here](http://oracle-database-tips.com/oracle_subquery.html) for a short tutorial).

Comment: yup cud u explain how it works. will accept ur in answer in 3 minutes

Comment: oh temp table. i created it before updating

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM atish_cust_order,atish_customer 
WHERE atish_cust_order.cust_nbr = atish_customer.cust_nbr gives total count. How come?

Comment: well, assuming every cust_nbr in `atish_cust_order` exists in `atish_customer`, then your SQL basically does an inner join on the two tables, then counts all the rows.  You might think of it as enumerating every row in the longer of the two tables - `atish_cust_order`, then for each of these rows looks up the corresponding `cust_nbr` in `atish_customer`.  The effect is just to count the total number of records in `atish_cust_order`.

Comment: @ganducoder:  I added a link to my answer that hopefully explains the correlated subquery better with an example.